# Have Google maps center around geo-locs and zoom in appropriately

Tags: api, google-maps

I would like to pass an x amount of geo-locations to the Google Maps API and have it centered around these locations and set the appropriate zoom level so all locations are visible on the map. I.e. show all the markers that are currently on the map.

Is this possible with what the Google Maps API offers by default or do I need to resolve to build this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this but it is pretty easy if you are using the V2 API. See this [post for an example](http://blog.jeromeparadis.com/archive/2007/02/08/1468.aspx), [this group post](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/996f83e075e51fdf/d1d67c0e17c5a490) or [this post](http://econym.googlepages.com/basic14.htm).

Comment: Note that the first link mentions that getBoundsZoomLevel() is undocumented - this is no longer true. I implemented something similiar for a project of mine, it works well - except I wish I knew about GBounds.extend() then!

Answer (score 9):

I used [fitBounds](http://code.google.com/intl/uk-UA/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) (API V3) for each point:

1. Declare the variable.

   ```
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   ```
2. Go through each marker with FOR loop

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
       bounds.extend(latlng);
   }
   ```
3. Finally call

   ```
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   ```

Comment: @camelCase: depends on your skill, +1 exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Moak you may want to add maxZoom to map object to prevent zooming too close!

Answer (score 2):

For V3 there's [zoomToMarkers](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=38223)

Answer (score 1):

Gray's Idea is great but does not work as is. I had to work out a hack for a **zoomToMarkers** API V3:

```
function zoomToMarkers(map, markers)
{
    if(markers[0]) // make sure at least one marker is there
    {
        // Get LatLng of the first marker
        var tempmark =markers[0].getPosition();

        // LatLngBounds needs two LatLng objects to be constructed
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(tempmark,tempmark);

        // loop thru all markers and extend the LatLngBounds object
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
        {
            bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
        }

        // Set the map viewport 
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

}
```